# Hibernate requires mapping of classes/tables. Already done

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a working ORM and been able to map objects to my database. So its up an running.

I've created a web service that looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("user")
@LocalBean
public class userFacade {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Fakebook3")
private EntityManager em;

public userFacade() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void persistUser(User user){
    em.persist(user);
}

@GET
@Path("edit")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response editUserInformation(
        @QueryParam("userid") int userid,
        @QueryParam("jobbText") String jobbText,
        @QueryParam("intresseText") String intresseText,
        @QueryParam("bostadText") String bostadText
        ){
    String jobbTextEscaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(jobbText);
    String intresseTextEscaString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(intresseText);
    String bostadTextEscaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(bostadText);
    String sql = "UPDATE user SET job=?, interest=?, bostad=? WHERE id="+userid;
    Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1, jobbTextEscaped);
    query.setParameter(2, intresseTextEscaString);
    query.setParameter(3, bostadTextEscaped);
    query.executeUpdate();

    return Response.status(200).entity("This is a callback message. Handle it!").build();
}
```

}

I'm using eclipse web service tool and input the paramater values and get this error:

```
13:23:41,184 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-4) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component userFacade for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response se.chas.fakebook.facade.userFacade.editUserInformation(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: fakebook.user is not mapped [UPDATE fakebook.user SET user.job=?, user.interests=?, user.bostad=? WHERE id=1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
```

and so on. I tried to create to map the entities using eclipse and placed them in the same folder as the entities.

But I'm still getting same exception. I also tried changing the sql statement from "... facebook.user ..." to only use "... user ..."

What am I doing wrong?

I can't upload images here so here comes a link with a project tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IMVg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE User SET job=?, interest=?, bostad=? WHERE id="+userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
```

UPDATE user SET job=:job, interest=:interest, bostad=:bostad WHERE id="+userid

```
query.setParameter("job", jobbTextEscaped);
query.setParameter("interest", intresseTextEscaString);
query.setParameter("bostad ", bostadTextEscaped);
```

Comment: It worked but I got a nullpointerException now? :) Also pleae upvote so i can upvote people that answers my question. Thanks

Comment: If this worked plz do upvote the answer too. It will  help me.Null pointer on what? Any details?

Comment: Post the null pointer exception. How is your EntityManager set?